# Python, TK: In a frame inside a (scrollable) canvas nothing is drawn beyond y > 0x7fff

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I use a frame inside a (scrollable) canvas (with canvas.create_window) to put elements in this frame (in my real application these are thumbnails of images).

When adding more frames it turns out nothing is drawn anymore beyond y > 0x7fff (which is the highest possible value of an 16 bit signed integer).

Tested with Python 3.8.0 64bit TK 8.6 on Windows 10 1809 and 1909.

Please consider the code below. When scrolling all the way down below y=0x7fff the frame is there but empty. When maximizing the main window you will notice that even the border of the inside frame is not drawn anymore.

My question: Is this a known limitation? Or do I do anything wrong? Or is this a bug? Also, if it is a bug a cannot say whether this bug is in tkinter or in tk itself.

(Note: I assigned the main frame (ImgCollection) as master of the inner _container (accidentally). The behavior changes a bit when the _canvas is assigned as master of the _container. But what remains the same is that drawing stops at y > 0x7fff.)

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

class ImgCollection(ttk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
      self._container = ttk.Frame(self)
      sb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical',
         command=self._canvas.yview)
      self._canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
      self._canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, expand=True)
      sb.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
      self._container.bind('<Configure>', self._onConfig)
      self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self._container,
         anchor=tk.NW)

   def add(self):
      frame = ttk.Frame(self._container, borderwidth=2, relief=tk.SOLID)
      canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=500, height=500)
      canvas.create_line(0, 0, 499, 499, width=8, fill='blue')
      canvas.create_line(0, 499, 499, 0, width=8, fill='blue')
      canvas.pack()
      frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

   def _onConfig(self, event):
      print(f'{event.height:x}')
      self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

gui = tk.Tk()
coll = ImgCollection(gui)
coll.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

for i in range(65):
   coll.add()
   gui.update()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Known limitation, coming from the X Windows graphics system on Unix that Tcl/Tk was originally written for.  I would guess that the limitation was intentionally copied to other platforms, to avoid situations where a program seems to work fine on one system, but isn't actually portable at all.

Comment: Relevant [display-an-extremly-long-image-in-tkinter-how-to-get-around-canvas-max limit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263155/how-do-i-display-an-extremly-long-image-in-tkinter-how-to-get-around-canvas-ma)

Answer (score 0):

> My question: Is this a known limitation?

Yes, it is a known limitation. The drawable area of the canvas is not infinite.